# xamarin.forms get byte array from imagesource

Tags: image, svg, xamarin.forms

I have svg xml that i can convert to ImageSource or FileImageSource by using XamSVG library in the PCL project of my xamarin.forms.

I want to convert the ImageSource  / FileImageSource to byte array (to get the bitmap).

Is this possible ?

Comment: Just refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532462/is-there-a-cross-platform-solution-to-imagesource-to-byte/27532867#27532867

Comment: this link isn't what i need since i am not using the camera. all i have is image with imagesource that i want to get the bitmap (byte array) from it

Answer (score 6):

ImageSource doesn't expose any mechanism to retrieve the original image source.  Instead, you will need to manually keep a reference to the original source you use to create the image.

Comment: I dont have original source - i have svg xml file that converts to imagefile, i need the byte array of the bitmap...

Comment: You will need to look at the XamSVG library to see if it produces an intermediary bitmap you can access, or modify it to produce one.

Answer (score 6):

I've found the solution.

```cs
StreamImageSource streamImageSource  = (StreamImageSource) some image source...
System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = System.Threading.CancellationToken.None;
Task<Stream> task = streamImageSource.Stream(cancellationToken);
Stream stream = task.Result;
```

Comment: and what is "a"? (3rd line)

Comment: a is streamImageSource

Comment: I juest tried that and I get: "Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource' to type 'Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource'."

Comment: This is not a solution - it only works if the `ImageSource` *is* of type `StreamImageSource`. It is not away to create an output stream of any `ImageSource`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```cs
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }          
}
```

`Stream` and `MemoryStream` are `System.IO` classes.

Then use it like this:

```cs
byte[] TargetImageByte = ReadFully(_data.Source);
```

`_data.source` is `MediaFile` type.