# How can I add my image inside my byte []? Xamarin Forms, C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a viewmodel with a byte that looks like this:

```
public byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

    }
```

And I reach it on my contentpage by doing this.

```
    CameraViewModel cameraOps = null;

    public PhotoPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    cameraOps = new CameraViewModel ();
```

And my clickfunction where I try to send the Byte to my DB:

```
async void createImage (object s, EventArgs a)
    {

    var createImagetheimg = await phpApi.createPhotoTwo (cameraOps.ReadStream (imgPicked.Source));

    //imgPicked is my image that I want to send.
    }
```

It does not let me add the image I want to send to my database inside the byte. I get the error: "Cannot convert Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource expresssion to type System.IO.Stream"
Do I need to adjust the "ReadStream" input?

THis is where I try to send the image into:

```
static public async Task <bool>  createPhotoTwo (byte [] imgData)
{   
    var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

    var postData = new Dictionary <string, object> ();

    postData.Add ("photoData", imgData);

    var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

    HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var result = await httpClientRequest.PostAsync("http://www.myadress.com/put.php", content);
    var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

    return  true;

}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
private async void btnPickPicture_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await cameraOps.SelectPicture ();
        var file = await cameraOps.SelectPicture();
        imgPicked.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.Source);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (imgPicked.Source);
        //StreamImageSource
        var createImagetheimg = await phpApi.createPhotoTwo (cameraOps.ReadStream (imgPicked.Source));
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception which is thrown?

Comment: "Cannot convert Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource expresssion to type System.IO.Stream"

Comment: Have you searched for the exception and checked the entries:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532462/is-there-a-cross-platform-solution-to-imagesource-to-byte)

Comment: you need two different things - a ImageSource and a byte[];  both of these can be created from a stream, but they are not interchangeable with one another.

Comment: Been googling a bit. Very unsure about how I should proceed. Should I do something with this: (Stream input, Image image) ? Like add another value in there?

Comment: No.  You have stream returned by your camera code.  You know how to create a StreamImageSource using a stream.  And you have the code you posted above to create a byte[] from a stream.

Comment: So inside the `var createImagetheimg = await phpApi.createPhotoTwo (cameraOps.ReadStream (*ADD IT HERE*));` I add the image that is an 'StreamImageSource'?

Comment: I would just create a byte[] at the same time you create your ImageSource, and then when you're ready to upload pass it that byte[].

Comment: Check out my updated code. When I run the image in the log now it is an StreamImageSource but it does not match with the System.IO.Stream